# How do I determine a formula for a given trig function?

Tags: trigonometry

Assume that 0 < x < pi/2 and sin(x) = z

a.) Find a formula that gives the value of sin(x/2) in terms of z

b.) Corroborate the validity of the formula for these values of x:

- pi/4
- pi/3
- pi/6

I know that it uses the first quadrant?

and sin(x/2) = +- sqrt((1-cos(x))/2)?

I don't get how I'm supposed to come up with a formula that give the value of sin(x/2) in terms of z though. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: It's going to look ugly...  You have a formula relating sine and cosine, correct?

Comment: What do you mean? I posted the info given. Do you mean the sin(x/2) part?

Answer (score 2):

We derive the result from the more familiar double-angle identity 
$$\cos 2t=1-2\sin^2 t.$$
(Probably $\cos 2t=2\cos^2 t -1$ is even more familiar. We can then get to $1-2\sin^2 t$ by replacing $\cos^2 t$ with $1-\sin^2 t$.)

Let $t=x/2$. Then 
$$2\sin^2 (x/2)=1-\cos x.$$
Now $\cos x=\pm\sqrt{1-\sin^2 x}$. But if our angle is between $0$ and $\pi/2$, then $\cos x$ is positive, and so is $\sin(x/2)$.

So we get $2\sin^2(x/2)=1-\sqrt{1-z^2}$, and therefore 
$$\sin(x/2)=\sqrt{\frac{1-\sqrt{1-z^2}}{2}}.\tag{$1$}$$

**Example:** Let $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$. Then $z=\sin(\pi/4)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Substitute in $(1)$. Note that $1-z^2=\frac{1}{2}$. So we get
$$\sin(\pi/8)=\sqrt{\frac{1-\sqrt{1/2}}{2}}.$$ 
One could make a further algebraic simplification.

**Remark:** It is actually worthwhile to do algebraic simplifications. By repeating the calculation, we can successively get expressions for $\sin(\pi/16)$, $\sin(\pi/32)$, and so on forever. If we do, we get a beautiful expression for $\pi$. In a quite different form, the idea goes back to Archimedes.

Comment: Hmm. Why did you start with cosine?

Comment: Confession time (you can check the edits!). I started with $\sin 2t=2\sin t\cos t$, replaced $\cos t$ by $\sqrt{1-\sin^2 t}$, squared both sides. We get a quadratic equation in $\sin^2 t$, which I solved. Straightforward, but kind of ugly. I wanted a nicer argument, so rewrote.

Comment: Hrmph. Not sure I'm following lol

Comment: Well, part of it is still visible if you go to Edit 3 (click on the "edited x minutes ago" link. Or trust me, it was uglier, but more natural.

Comment: Ok I believe you lol. So would I just take that last equation, plug in the x's, and solve for z essentially?

Comment: I assume you are now asking about the answer as it is now. I will add a specific computation for one of the questions you were asked. Less than $10$ minutes!

Comment: Yeah. I think I understand how you got the formula for the most part. But I tried working it out on paper and I've gotten like 3 different answers

Comment: Ok thank you! My last question is regarding the final solution. Why is it sin(pi/8) instead of sin(pi/4)?

Comment: Because we are calculating $\sin(x/2)$ where $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$.